# C# IpcChannel Remote connection failed (when actually remoting)

Tags: c#, ipc

I tried to implement the IpcChannel from this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.ipc.ipcchannel(v=vs.110).aspx

However, it does not matter which port is used in

```
        IpcChannel serverChannel =
        new IpcChannel("127.0.0.1:9090");
```

tcpview does not show the port as "Listening".

The example does work with localhost, but with another computer as client, obviously not. (Because of the no-listening state of the port)
I can enter any string into the `IpcChannel()` part. So even `IpcChannel("blabla123")` will "start" the server.

Is this intended or am I making a mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: Using `HttpChannel` or `TcpChannel`.

The documentation of the IPC example is ambiguous. The use of a hostname and port made me think this was also network capable.